# how to grant permission to execute env on Centos

Tags: linux, centos

How can I grant permission for user to run command `env` whenever I call it, I get

```
bash: /bin/env: Permission denied
```

noting the user is sudo

```
ls -lL /usr/bin/env -rwxr--r--. 1 root root 29048 Oct 30 21:16 /usr/bin/env

sudo env
```

works okey

```
env
```

produces

```
permission denied
```

Comment: What are the permissions of `/bin/env`? Can you run it as another user or does it not work at all?

Comment: am able to run as root

Comment: And what are the permissions of the `/bin/env` file (and whatever file it points to if it is a symbolic link)?

Comment: ls -lL /usr/bin/env
-rwxr--r--. 1 root root 29048 Oct 30 21:16 /usr/bin/env

Comment: When you say, "the user is sudo" do you mean you are running the `/bin/env` command as `root` with `sudo` or another user with `sudo -u <user>` ?

Comment: I mean, user <sw> is listed as sudo user in env  ... SUDO_USER=sw

Comment: Does this mean that `sudo /bin/env` works? In this case, which command does not work exactly?

Comment: sudo /bin/env works,  but directly typing env directly produces Permission denied

Comment: This is consistent with the permissions of the `/usr/bin/env` file (only the owner, `root` in this case, has execute permissions). I'm unsure whether the permissions are normal and will check that in a clean install.

Comment: I have to highlight that it was working normally before